# Twitter Bootstrap: Nested modal popup doesn't fade

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have the following markup using a twitter bootstrap modal plugin nested within a .tabbable div:

```
    <div class="tabbable">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#tabPeople" data-toggle="tab">People</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabRoles" data-toggle="tab">Roles</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="tabPeople">
                <a data-toggle="modal" href="#modalEditPerson1">Name</a>
                <div class="modal hide fade in" id="modalEditPerson1">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                            ×</button>
                        <h3>
                            Name</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>
                            One fine body…</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">
                            Save changes</a>
                    </div>
                </div>                   
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="tabRoles">
                <p>
                    Role stuff here.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This brings up a modal, but doesn't fade it as in the demo on this page: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals

It works fine when it is not nested inside the .tabbable element

Header contains  this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="styles/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="styles/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/styles/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: its working fine for me, http://jsfiddle.net/WAnU8/, what is your js loading order?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added the js links in the main post.

Comment: Hmm, everything should work fine with your setup, aside from the fact that you're supposed to load the bootstrap stylesheet above all else but that is only an aside. Is there any modifications you have made to the bootstrap? In my fiddle above everything works as expected running the stock bootstrap stylesheet and plugins so it must be something else in your setup. Can you recreate your setup over at http://jsfiddle.net to take a look?

Comment: Found it. I had a jquery selector that was selecting more than it should elsewhere on the page. It was capturing the click event on my modal anchor and overriding the default behaviour. Thanks for your help. Although you didn't directly answer my query, it was your suggestions that led me to the answer. Thanks for that! (if you put it in an answer I can mark it likewise...)

Comment: Just post your results in the form of an answer below with an answer and findings and mark it as correct, that way it can help future users with the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. I had a jquery selector elsewhere on the page that was selecting more than it should. It was capturing the click event on my modal anchors and overriding the default behavior. Thanks for everyone's help/input.